# Odoo 10, upload file

Tags: file, pdf, upload, png, odoo-10

is it possible, in odoo 10, to upload a file in the form of a given model ? 
The user of the custom module has a list of items that he receives from is clients and he needs the invoices of thoses items. I imagine that this files are pdf files, but not necessarely (But I can tell to upload pdfs only if that is simple...).

The problem is, some times, in other technologies, a file is uploaded, but cannot be read when it is downloaded (some kind of corruption). So I really need to know how to do this in the sipliest and correct way.

Thank you So much for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your model's py file

```
upload_file = fields.Binary(string="Upload File")
file_name = fields.Char(string="File Name")
```

in your xml form view file:

```
<field name="upload_file" filename="file_name"/>
<field name="file_name" invisible="1"/>
```

after uploading and saving file the download button shows and file retrived in save format which is uploaded

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much... Will try that. Have searched all other for this :P

Comment: hi there can u show the function to get the file upload?